# Viewer for OpenInventor (*.iv) files on Windows?

Tags: windows

What is the best way to view OpenInventor *.iv files in Windows 7?

On Linux, there is ivview, which is part of the inventor-clients package (Debian 6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at some of [these](http://merlin.fit.vutbr.cz/wiki/index.php/Open_Inventor_Tools) tools. I have never used them, but they seem to do what you are looking for.